# Ajax, enviar dados sem atualizar a página

Tags: ajax

Bom, eu fiz uma integração Restful API, que busca todos os produtos de um e-commerce e manda o Json para outro site, e precisava que, ao clicar no botão "Enviar", a página não atualizasse.

O meu problema é o seguinte, não há dados para inserir em formulário, basicamente, utilizo o form apenas para colocar o botão de envio

```
        <div style="position:absolute; margin-left: 65%;margin-top: -500px">
<form action="" method="post" id="formenv">
<button style="width:60px" type="submit"     class="btn btn-primary" id="expevt" name="expevt">
     <dt style="text-align:center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
        <b></b>
        </button>
```

Somente sei utilizar o ajax para enviar os dados de um formulário, porém, esse botão, apenas chama o Post da integração,

```
    if(isset($_POST))
{
    if (isset($_POST['expevt']))
    {
        $post2 = new Posts();

        if(isset( $_POST['catwooid']) && $_POST['catwooid'] != '')
        {
            $post2->postOneCat($_POST['catwooid']);
        }else
        {
            $post2->postAllCat();
        }
        $post = new Posts();
        if(isset( $_POST['prodwoosku']) && $_POST['prodwoosku'] != '')
        {
            $post->postOneProd($_POST['prodwoosku']);
        }else
        {
            $post->postAllProd();
        }
    }
}
```

Teria como eu fazer o post sem dar refresh?

Comment: Existe um script no qual essa integração é rodada, correto? Você tem um formulario com um botão no qual não tem nenhuma action, o script roda na mesma pagina? Os codigos ficaram um pouco confusos no contexto, eu imagino que a solução seja bem simples caso tenha um arquivo ja rodando toda essa integração, basta que o clique seja capturado, faça um prevendefault() e chame o script no ajax...

Answer (score -1):

Você pode colocar um `return false` no seu form e o resto faz normal

```js
$('#expevt').on('click', function(){
   alert('Aqui você vai fazer seu ajax enviar' )
   //$.ajax()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
<div >
        <form action="" method="post" id="formenv">
             <button style="width:60px" type="submit"    class="btn btn-primary" id="expevt" name="expevt">
                  <dt style="text-align:center">
                  Botão
                  <b></b>
                  </dt>
              </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```